# Tool to Unminify / Decompress JavaScript

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, minify, compression, unminify

Are there any command line scripts and/or online tools that can reverse the effects of minification similar to how Tidy can clean up horrific HTML?

(I'm specifically looking to unminify a minified JavaScript file, so variable renaming might still be an issue.)

Comment: For those of you who may not be aware, minification changes internal variable names to a single letter and removes code comments.  Undoing these changes cannot be automated.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Good point. I've edited the question so it no longer implies that minification does not change variable names.

Comment: FWIW... just found JS NICE http://www.jsnice.org/

Comment: http://marcusjenkins.com/linux/de-minify-javascript-on-the-command-line/ worked well for me.

Comment: For @DanielAllenLangdon: jsnice.org can unminify and de-obfuscate even 30k angularjs code.

Answer (score 510, accepted):

You can use this : http://jsbeautifier.org/
But it depends on the minify method you are using, this one only formats the code, it doesn't change variable names, nor uncompress base62 encoding.

edit: in fact it can unpack "packed" scripts (packed with Dean Edward's packer : http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

Comment: did you mean base64 encoding?  I've never heard of base62 encoding...

Comment: Nope, I said base 62 : http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_62

Comment: is there such a thing as a tool that "changes variable names" and is still aware of JS syntax to not break the code?

Comment: Fantastic. I just solved my problem, then emailed the author of the framework with the exact fix.

Answer (score 161):

Chrome developer tools has this feature built-in. Bring up the developer tools (pressing F12 is one way), in the Sources tab, the bottom left bar has a set of icons. The "{}" icon is "Pretty print" and does this conversion on demand.

UPDATE: IE9 "F12 developer tools" also has a "Format JavaScript" feature in the Script tab under the Tools icon there. (*see* Tip #4 in [F12 The best kept web debugging secret](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/10/18/f12-the-best-kept-web-debugging-secret.aspx))

[image]

Comment: For the particular .js I was trying to un-minify, this method worked the best, cheers.

Comment: This is now in the "Sources" tab, not the Scripts tab.

Comment: @mhenry1384: Yes, Chrome did rename the tab. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: YES!! (our app does not have a debug/dev mode for js that I am aware of -- we thankfully do not shorten/transform variable names.)

Comment: Just a heads-up: Chrome sometimes messes up the JavaScript code. For instance, `if (a) /regex/.match(foo);` is pretty printed as `if (a)\n    / /regex/ .\nmatch(foo);` which is a syntax error.

Comment: Firefox does this as well.  On the current version, you right-click on the tab for the file you want to examine and select Pretty Print source.

Answer (score 58):

Got it! [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) does exactly this, and you even have options for the auto-formatting.

Comment: stackoverflow-then-google instead of google-then-stackoverflow? :))))

Comment: I did the google for "javascript formatter online"

Comment: This FireFox plugin uses JSBeautifier to un-minify javascript so you can then set breakpoints on lines in FireBug's js debugger!!: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/

Answer (score 16):

Can't you just use a javascript formatter (http://javascript.about.com/library/blformat.htm) ?

Comment: +1 for answer that also works. fabien just happened to reply first

Comment: This only answer the "decompress" part of the question.

Comment: Nope this is not working good. It break the code... :(

Answer (score 14):

In Firefox, SpiderMonkey and Rhino you can wrap any code into an anonymous function and call its [`toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) method, which will give you a nicely formatted source of the function.

`toSource` also strips comments.

*E. g.*:

```
(function () { /* Say hello. */ var x = 'Hello!'; print(x); }).toSource()
```

Will be converted to a string:

```
function () {
    var x = "Hello!";
    print(x);
}
```

*P. S.*: It's not an "online tool", but all questions about general beautifying techniques are closed as duplicates of this one.

Comment: Interesting. I asked the question 2.5 years ago so I feel it's too late to edit the title, but I still like seeing both online and offline options. Thanks for chiming in. +1

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more on firefox

Answer (score 10):

If you have a Mac and TextMate - An easy alternative for formatting Javascript is:

1. Open the file with Textmate.
2. Click on > Bundles > JavaScript > Reformat Document
3. Crack open a beer.

Comment: Beer being served right now :)

Answer (score 7):

Most of the IDEs also offer auto-formatting features. For example **in NetBeans, just press CTRL+K**.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative (since I didn't know about jsbeautifier.org until now), I have used a bookmarklet that reenabled the decode button in Dean Edward's Packer.

I found the instructions and bookmarklet [here](http://yaisb.blogspot.com/2006/10/defeating-dean-edwards-javascript.html).

here is the bookmarklet (in case the site is down)

```
javascript:for%20(i=0;i<document.forms.length;++i)%20{for(j=0;j<document.forms[i].elements.length;++j){document.forms[i].elements[j].removeAttribute(%22readonly%22);document.forms[i].elements[j].removeAttribute(%22disabled%22);}}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you need source code. There is a free online JavaScript formatter at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Resources/JSFormatter.aspx.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one, with code coloration:

http://labs.swelen.com/tools/javascript/beauty.html

Answer (score 5):

click on these link for JS deminification. That will install on FF as extension that help you in debugging js at runtime.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/eula/141018?src=dp-btn-primary

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122183/stone)'s answer, but for Windows/.NET developers:

If you have Visual Studio and ReSharper - An easy alternative for formatting Javascript is:

- Open the file with Visual Studio;
- Click on ReSharper > Tools > Cleanup Code (Ctrl+E, C);
- Select "Default: Reformat code", and click OK;
- Crack open a beer.

Answer (score 4):

Despite its miles-away-from-being-pretty interface, [JSPretty](http://www.jspretty.com/) is a good, free and online tool for making javascript source codes human-readable. You can enforce your preferred type of indentation and it can also detect obfuscation.

Answer (score 3):

If one is in JS possibility of using Firefox is more. And if its Firefox add on is for rescue. Following one is particularly useful.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/phoenix/

Answer (score 3):

**[Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify)** will beautify (pretty print) JavaScript in a way that conforms to [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) and [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) white space algorithms.

Comment: It's ironic the site is so un-pretty, but this is a cool tool.

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't really happy with the output of jsbeautifier.org for what I was putting in, so I did some more searching and found this site: http://www.centralinternet.com.br/javascript-beautifier

Worked extremely well for me.

Answer (score 2):

http://unminify.appspot.com/
Great tools for unminify javascript and json