# Tool to reverse Javascript minify?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, minify, unminify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online Tool to Unminify / Decompress JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/online-tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript)

Online javascript minify tools basically strip out comments and whitespace.

Is there a tool that can reverse this? Taking what is usually a single line of code:

```
function(){var K=o.timers;for(var J=0;J<K.length;J++){if(!K[J]()){K.splice(J--,1)}}if(!K.length){clearInterval(n);n=g}}
```

and auto-formatting it so you can begin reverse-engineering it?

```
function(){
    var K=o.timers;
    for(var J=0;J<K.length;J++){
        if(!K[J]()){
            K.splice(J--,1);
        }
    }
    if(!K.length){
        clearInterval(n);
        n=g;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/unminify-decompress-javascript