# How to deminify javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online Tool to Unminify / Decompress JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/online-tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript)
>   [Tool to reverse Javascript minify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028138/tool-to-reverse-javascript-minify)

Is there a way to convert minified JavaScript code into normal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/online-tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript

Comment: http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker

Answer (score 33):

http://jsbeautifier.org/ works like a charm.

Most software distributed under the GPL license will also provide non-minified code.

Comment: It does not de-obfuscate names of variables.

Comment: @Green how would it do that? You would have to give it a list of the original variable names and their obfuscated counterparts.

Comment: @clayRay you are correct. Please check out source maps. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: @Bob9630 thanks, very interesting! Has the idea been adopted more widely since the article was written in 2012? I've Googled it and it still seems largely a Mozilla thing. Someone has created a NuGet package for DotNet, but this still seems in prototype stage.

Comment: @clayRay Source maps are supported by at least Firefox, Safari, Chrome (and Opera), IE/Edge. There are also plenty of tools available outside the browser (many on npm); from the top of my head I also know that there is a Python implementation, and I would not be surprised if there was an implementation in your favorite language.

Answer (score 5):

I use WebStorm by JetBrains for my Javascript IDE, it has auto-format which seems to do the trick pretty well.

Comment: Also it is possible in phpstorm. Menu "Code" -> "Reformat Code" or Ctrl+Alt+L

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's native object inspector will format JS for you, but it won't be able to make sense of the variable names - nothing will.

If you want an online solution, use [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). It works well, and is also very handy for making sense of some of the questions you see here on StackOverflow.

Comment: 'nothing will' I mean a human stepping through the code could. It might be nice to have a tool to "fill back in the values that a human knows"