# Decode script file(.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, deobfuscation

I have the following encrypted script:

```
eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = function (c) {
        return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
        k = [function (e) {
                return r[e]
            }
        ];
        e = function () {
            return '\\w+'
        };
        c = 1
    };
    while (c--) if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
}('z(t(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=t(c){u c.F(a)};v(!\'\'.x(/^/,A)){y(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[t(e){u r[e]}];e=t(){u\'\\\\w+\'};c=1};y(c--)v(k[c])p=p.x(B C(\'\\\\b\'+e(c)+\'\\\\b\',\'g\'),k[c]);u p}(\'h(6(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=8;9(!\\\'\\\'.d(/^/,8)){f(c--)r[c]=k[c]||c;k=[6(e){7 r[e]}];e=6(){7\\\'\\\\\\\\i+\\\'};c=1};f(c--)9(k[c])p=p.d(j l(\\\'\\\\\\\\b\\\'+e(c)+\\\'\\\\\\\\b\\\',\\\'g\\\'),k[c]);7 p}(\\\'$(0).1(2(){3("4")});\\\',5,5,\\\'m|n|6|o|q\\\'.s(\\\'|\\\'),0,{}))\',D,D,\'||||||t|u|A|v||||x||y||z|w|B||C|G|H|I||J||E\'.E(\'|\'),0,{}))', 46, 46, '|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||function|return|if||replace|while|eval|String|new|RegExp|29|split|toString|document|ready|alert|hi'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

Can anyone decrypt the script and let me know the source code?

Comment: What have you already tried? SO isn't a place to get free work done.

Comment: Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to un-minify the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to reverse Javascript minify?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028138/tool-to-reverse-javascript-minify)

Comment: http://yaisb.blogspot.it/2006/10/defeating-dean-edwards-javascript.html read this

Comment: Please stop it with the minus votes and the reports. That's a perfect legitimate question and I am interested to see somebody deobfuscating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hi")
});`

Comment: Thank you. how did you decrypt this? Kindly let us know the link of the decoder you used.

Comment: http://ilearnzone.blogspot.ca/2012/08/online-javascript-unpacker-and.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you. can you suggest an efficient way to hide the javascript?

Comment: Can you not just remove that snippet of code if you do not simply want to use it?

Answer (score 2):

First get the reEnable bookmarklet from [here](http://yaisb.blogspot.it/2006/10/defeating-dean-edwards-javascript.html) then go to [Dean Edward Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

Click the bookmarklet to enable the text area and press decode multiple times to get the message:

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("hi")});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the [Dean Edwards /packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/):

Also, to see the code deobfuscated, simply replace the `eval` with `alert`, or simply use his unpacker:

- **[Dean Edwards Unpacker](http://dean.edwards.name/unpacker/)**
- **[JSUnpack](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/)**

Unpacked code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert("hi")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one ,create html file and in script tag do something below one

this

```
     <script>
      eval(function(p, a,...);
     <script/>
```

to

```
     <script>
      document.write(function(p, a,...);
     <script/>
```

Comment: this is beacuse code is compress two time so you have to perform this step two time

Comment: @ Ahmad Alfy you can unpack file with this if it is compress one time you can try it also

Comment: yes i tried it 3 times and it worked