# can I get the facebook all.js file as a not-minified (expanded) file?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm running into a bug when working with facebook's all.js. I get the line number of the bug, but that line is wow huge. Does facebook provide a "non-minified" version of that all.js file? That would really help me figure out what is going on and step through it..

Related: [Tool to Unminify / Decompress JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/online-tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript) <-- this link does the trick, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a de-minified version that is provided by facebook. De-minifying it myself might introduce bugs which would cause me to chase down bugs that don't exist in the original source code.

Comment: A handy tip for this is to use the Chrome 'pretty print' button - click the button with { } in the bottom left of a source tab in DevTools. That said, it's not perfect, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: Yes, very handy. Wish it was around when I needed it 4.5 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latest update on 2013:

Facebook has removed the source from GitHub, instead they provide the debug version (non-minfied) from the link below:

http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js

Answer (score 1):

The source code is available on [github](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js), as mentioned on the [Facebook javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) page.

Comment: The GitHub repo is no longer maintained. Use http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js instead.