# How to edit minimized jQuery plugin file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, minimized

I want to edit supersized.3.1.3.core.min.js file.

Here's the code (placed here temporarily):

```
(function(a){a(document).ready(function(){a("body").prepend('<div id="supersized-loader"></div>').append('<div id="supersized"></div>')});a.supersized=function(b){var d={start_slide:1,vertical_center:0,horizontal_center:0,min_width:0,min_height:0,fit_portrait:0,fit_landscape:0,image_protect:1};var c=a("#supersized");if(b){var b=a.extend(d,b)}else{var b=a.extend(d)}if(b.start_slide){var f=b.start_slide-1}else{var f=Math.floor(Math.random()*b.slides.length)}a("<img/>").attr("src",b.slides[f].image).appendTo(c);c.hide();a(document).ready(function(){e()});a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");e()});a(window).resize(function(){e()});function e(){return c.each(function(){var g=a("img",c);a(g).each(function(){var i=(a(this).height()/a(this).width()).toFixed(2);thisSlide=a(this);var h=a(window).width();var k=a(window).height();var l;if((k<=b.min_height)&&(h<=b.min_width)){if((k/h)>i){b.fit_landscape&&i<=1?j(true):m(true)}else{b.fit_portrait&&i>1?m(true):j(true)}}else{if(h<=b.min_width){if((k/h)>i){b.fit_landscape&&i<=1?j(true):m()}else{b.fit_portrait&&i>1?m():j(true)}}else{if(k<=b.min_height){if((k/h)>i){b.fit_landscape&&i<=1?j():m(true)}else{b.fit_portrait&&i>1?m(true):j()}}else{if((k/h)>i){b.fit_landscape&&i<=1?j():m()}else{b.fit_portrait&&i>1?m():j()}}}}function j(n){if(n){if(thisSlide.width()<h||thisSlide.width()<b.min_width){if(thisSlide.width()*i>=b.min_height){thisSlide.width(b.min_width);thisSlide.height(thisSlide.width()*i)}else{m()}}}else{if(b.min_height>=k&&!b.fit_landscape){if(h*i>=b.min_height||(h*i>=b.min_height&&i<=1)){thisSlide.width(h);thisSlide.height(h*i)}else{if(i>1){thisSlide.height(b.min_height);thisSlide.width(thisSlide.height()/i)}else{if(thisSlide.width()<h){thisSlide.width(h);thisSlide.height(thisSlide.width()*i)}}}}else{thisSlide.width(h);thisSlide.height(h*i)}}}function m(n){if(n){if(thisSlide.height()<k){if(thisSlide.height()/i>=b.min_width){thisSlide.height(b.min_height);thisSlide.width(thisSlide.height()/i)}else{j(true)}}}else{if(b.min_width>=h){if(k/i>=b.min_width||i>1){thisSlide.height(k);thisSlide.width(k/i)}else{if(i<=1){thisSlide.width(b.min_width);thisSlide.height(thisSlide.width()*i)}}}else{thisSlide.height(k);thisSlide.width(k/i)}}}if(b.horizontal_center){a(this).css("left",(h-a(this).width())/2)}if(b.vertical_center){a(this).css("top",(k-a(this).height())/2)}});if(b.image_protect){a("img",c).bind("contextmenu",function(){return false});a("img",c).bind("mousedown",function(){return false})}return false})}}})(jQuery);
```

I want to add my custom line of code:

```
$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow');
```

inside this bit:

```
a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");e()});
```

to make the #content div fade in slowly after the background image is faded in.

I did this in the non-minimized version, like this:

```
    $(window).load(function(){

            $('#supersized-loader').hide();     //Hide loading animation
            element.fadeIn('fast');             //Fade in background

            resizenow();

$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow'); //my bit of code

        });
```

– but I would very much like to know how to do the same in the minimized code.

I would appreciate expertly advice!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/online-tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript

Comment: why not just minify the edited uncompressed version?

Comment: Are you asking how to rename things so your own addition is minified? Otherwise, you just add it like you would to the non-minified version.

Comment: posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: @kinakuta I tried adding the way I would add in non-minimized version: a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow');e()}); and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you help please?

Comment: @David Wick, thank you for making your comment clearer and supplying the answer! I learned something useful from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make the changes to the not-min version of the .js file and then pack it back up using one of several web tools.  Since the .min version is just a packed up full .js file, you should be good to go.

Here's one that is useful: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: Thank you LeGrande, this is beautiful and worked like a clock!

Answer (score 1):

why not work with the unminimized code, add yours, test everything to your satisfaction, and *then* minimize again?

Of course, you can simply strip whitespace out of your fragement-to-insert and plug it right in, yielding

```
a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");e();a('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow')});
```

Assuming that `e()` is `resizenow()`, which is a reasonable guess.

Comment: This one doesn't work unfortunately: a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");e();$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow')});

Comment: YES! Works with a! Thank you Tucuxi!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
a(window).load(function(){a("#supersized-loader").hide();c.fadeIn("fast");$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('slow');e()});
```

Comment: Then I'd go with @David Wick suggestion...I was thinking the same as an alternative.

Comment: I think that call to 'e()' may be important

Answer (score 0):

why not just minify the edited uncompressed version?

see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ for details on how.