# Replace ,(comma) by .(dot) and .(dot) by ,(comma)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a string as `"1,23,45,448.00"` and I want to replace all commas by decimal point and all decimal points by comma.

My required output is "1.23.45.448,00"

I've tried to replace `,` by `.` as follow:

```
var mystring = "1,23,45,448.00"
alert(mystring.replace(/,/g , "."));
```

But, after that, if I try to replace `.` by `,` it also replaces the first replaced `.` by `,` resulting in giving the output as `"1,23,45,448,00"`

Comment: So? What's isn't working for you?

Comment: @AdamAzad When first replaced `.`(_or comma_) will make the other replace revert the first replace.

Comment: @Tushar, these details should be present in the question, rather than in a comment. Good quality questions should describe the issue well enough without the need to add **essential** to the problem details in comments. A good description flow is to say **1) what I want to happen** then **2) what I am doing** and finally **3) what actually happens**

Comment: @IvayloSlavov You're right, as this is first question of OP, the quality of question is _low_, edited to add more details. :)

Comment: @Tushar, that is now way better. Glad to see quality improvement advices taken seriously :)

Comment: If JS had hashes and interpolated variables at runtime, you could just put the replacement as `{hash[$1]}`, where `hash["."] = ","` and `hash[","] = "."`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `replace` with callback function which will replace `,` by `.` and `.` by `,`. The returned value from the function will be used to replace the matched value.

```js
var mystring = "1,23,45,448.00";

mystring = mystring.replace(/[,.]/g, function (m) {
    // m is the match found in the string
    // If `,` is matched return `.`, if `.` matched return `,`
    return m === ',' ? '.' : ',';
});

//ES6
mystring = mystring.replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','))

console.log(mystring);
document.write(mystring);
```

**Regex:** The regex `[,.]` will match any one of the comma or decimal point.

[`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the function callback will get the match as parameter(`m`) which is either `,` or `.` and the value that is returned from the function is used to replace the match.

So, when first `,` from the string is matched

```
m = ',';
```

And in the function `return m === ',' ? '.' : ',';`

is equivalent as

```
if (m === ',') {
    return '.';
} else {
    return ',';
}
```

So, basically this is replacing `,` by `.` and `.` by `,` in the string.

Comment: Could you please explain more what's going on in this line: `return m === ',' ? '.' : ',';`

Comment: @snookieordie, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8897859/2151050) for future.

Comment: @snookieordie When m==',' at that time it will replaced into '.' other wise ',' will accepted.'?' conditional operator.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing wrong with Tushar's approach, but here's another idea:

```
myString
  .replace(/,/g , "__COMMA__") // Replace `,` by some unique string
  .replace(/\./g, ',')         // Replace `.` by `,`
  .replace(/__COMMA__/g, '.'); // Replace the string by `.`
```