# Regex to replace pairs %s, \s correctly even with %% and \\

Tags: regex

I would like to find a regex that would replace `%%` with `%` and `%s` with my custom string `foobar`. This is tricker that it sounds, because it should turn `%%s` into `%s` and *not* `%foobar`, so this naive implementation does not work:

```
s/%%/%/g
s/%s/foobar/g
```

This problem is quite common and I've come across it multiple times in my programming life. Not just percent s or percent escaping, but also backslash character or backlash escaping. I'm going to post my usual solution but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

(Allow me to do some keyword stuffing for my future searches: character pairs, backslash backslash, backslash x, percent percent, percent s. Thank you.)

If there are specific language features that would help in this use-case, I'd be interested in hearing what they are.

#### Example input and output:

```
input  : test %%, test %s, test %%s too
output : test %, test foobar, test %s too
```

Another one:

```
input  : test%%,test%s,test%%stoo
output : test%,testfoobar,test%stoo
```

Comment: keyword stuffing ? You could just star your own question for easy retrieval... as it stands, the offending paragraph will most likely be deleted without notice.

Comment: @SirDarius I hope not because I am genuinely trying to be helpful to Googlers everywhere, including myself, it has happened to me that I've found my own answers on SO after searching on Google for a solution that I've forgotten about. Also, searching for %s %% \\ and so on is a *pain* on Google.

Comment: Language? And do your symbols always have e.g. empty spaces around them? Because matching against `\b%%\b` would accomplish that. e.g. do you have to ever match `%%someword` or `stuff%%morestuff`?

Comment: Then it means that the problem is not correctly enunciated, because it might apply to any character, not only  '\', '%'. Your litteral characters will not help people searching for a solution for a similar problem with, say `$$` :)

Comment: Similar/Dupe [Replace ,(comma) by .(dot) and .(dot) by ,(comma)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238005/replace-comma-by-dot-and-dot-by-comma) The base problem is same, once first thing is replaced, second `replace()` will override the first replaced string.

Comment: @Sobrique: no, the symbols do not always have empty spaces around them. `test%%test%stest%%stoo` should turn into `test%testfoobartest%stoo`.

Comment: Can I suggest some example input/output would help this question?

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified and can be done in single `replace` call:

```
var str = "test %s, test %%, test %%s too";
var output = str.replace(/%%|(%s)/g, function($0, $1){
     return $1!==undefined?'foobar':'%'; });
//=> test foobar, test %, test %s too
```

We use alternation first `/%%/(%s)/` and use a capturing group while matching `(%s)`. In the `replace callback` we use `$1!==undefined` to decide what string to be used as replacer.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with regular expressions is - if you run them twice, they get applied twice.

So yes - you're implementation isn't going to work, because you 'search twice' - after your first replace, you have no way to tell the difference.

So how about instead;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %replace = ( '%%' => '%',  
                '%s' => 'foobar' );

my $search = join ( "|", keys %replace );
   $search = qr/($search)/; 

print "Search regex: $search\n";
while ( <DATA> ) {
   s/$search/$replace{$1}/g;
   print;
}

##output : test %, test foobar, test %s too
##output : test%,testfoobar,test%stoo

__DATA__
test %%, test %s, test %%s too
test%%,test%s,test%%stoo
```

That's doing it perlishly, but you're building a lookup table - capturing the left hand side, and looking up what it should replace with on the right. (You can turn this into a one liner too).

Output:

```
Search regex: (?^:(%%|%s))
test %, test foobar, test %s too
test%,testfoobar,test%stoo
```

Pretty sure you should be able to implement this in most languages.

As an alternative, it's probably worth considering regex [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which lets you - if you do your regexs in the opposite order:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   s/(?<!%)%s/foobar/g;
   s/%%/%/g;
   print;
}

##output : test %, test foobar, test %s too
##output : test%,testfoobar,test%stoo

__DATA__
test %%, test %s, test %%s too
test%%,test%s,test%%stoo
```

`(?<!%)` is a zero width assertion that says 'not preceeded by a percent' - so it runs through and replaces *just* `%s` with "foobar" (but ignores `%%s`). And then applies the secondary transform, which doesn't catch 'foobar' because it doesn't have a `%%` in there.

Output:

```
test %, test foobar, test %s too
test%,testfoobar,test%stoo
```

Downside of this approach is that not all languages properly support look around. (It's an 'advanced regex' thing, not 'basic')

Comment: Why did you decide to edit out the lookaround solution? That was interesting and unlike the other answers, and I upvoted it.

Comment: Re-editing it in, based on test data. Realised I'd made a silly mistake (omitted the 'g' flag)

Answer (score 1):

The general problem of escape sequences is not optimally solved by regular expression substitution.

You have to think of your string as a sequence of tokens evaluated lexically by a state machine.

You start by being in a `NORMAL` state.
In the normal state, any character that you encounter is copied-as-is to the output, unless it is a `%`, in which case you enter a state `PERCENT`.
In that state, you can encounter a `%`, then you output `%` and return to `NORMAL`.
You can also encounter a `s`, and then you pop the next substitution string, output it, and return to `NORMAL`.
Finally depending on the behavior you need, any other character encountered in the `PERCENT` state can yield an error, or be ignored...

Example javascript code:

```
function parseString(s, vars) {
    var NORMAL = 0, PERCENT = 1;

    var state = NORMAL;
    var varidx = 0;
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <  s.length; i++) {
        if (state == NORMAL) {
            if (s[i] == '%') {
                state = PERCENT;
            } else {
                output += s[i];
            }
        } else if (state == PERCENT) {
            if (s[i] == '%') {
                output += s[i];
                state = NORMAL;
            } else if (s[i] == 's') {
                output += vars[varidx++];
                state = NORMAL;
            } else {
                throw 'Invalid syntax';
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Example:

```
parseString("test %%, test %s, test %%s too", ['foo']);
// returns "test %, test foo, test %s too"
```

While this approach is more code than regexp-based solutions, it is probably faster because regular expressions involve a much greater degree of complexity, and it allows you to handle invalid syntax the way that fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

This is one easy way of doing it. Split the string into an array of chunks, for lack of better term, using the regex `/%%|%s|./`, so that each chunk is a character or an escaped character, and then check each individual chunk for `%s` and `%%` like this, do the unescaping, and join the array again, like this:

```
Input  : "test %s, test %%, test %%s too"
Array  : ["t", "e", "s", "t", " ", "%s", ",", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t", " ", "%%",
          " ", "t", "e", "s", "t", "%%", "s", " ", "t", "o", "o"]
Output : "test foobar, test %, test %s too"
```

Here is the same idea in Javascript without using a variable to hold the chunks:

```
var str = "test %s, test %%, test %%s too";
var output = str.replace(/%%|%s|./g, function(match, capture) { 
  return match.replace("%%", "%").replace("%s", "foobar");
});
console.log("output:", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) way to replace `%%` by `%` and `%s` by `foobar`.

```
string.replace(/%%|%s/g, function (match) {
    // If %% is matched, replace it by %
    // else %s is matched, replace by `foobar`
    return match === '%%' ? '%' : 'foobar';
});
```

```js
var str = "test %s, test %%, test %%s too";

str = str.replace(/%%|%s/g, function (_) {
    return _ === '%%' ? '%' : 'foobar';
});

console.log(str);
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Using this approach, [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is used only once, instead of three times as in other answers.

---

Here's another approach using the variable swap logic using temp variable.
Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239612/2025923) by [@torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo)

```
str
    .replace(/%%/g, '2percent') // Replace first string by some string that will not possibly be appear/present in the main string
    .replace(/%s/g, 'foobar') // Replace second string
    .replace(/2percent/g, '%'); // Replace temp by the normal string
```

```js
var str = "test %s, test %%, test %%s too";

str = str
    .replace(/%%/g, '2percent')
    .replace(/%s/g, 'foobar')
    .replace(/2percent/g, '%');

console.log(str);
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Sorry just noticed your answer after posting mine. I will leave it for now as there is some difference in approaches (checking for matched string vs checking for presence of a captured group)

Comment: @anubhava No prob. and no need to say sorry.

Comment: The first approach looks good but the second approach would fail in corner-cases where the input string has `2percent` in it.

Comment: @Flimm That's what I've said in the comments, use the temp string which is less likely present in the actual string.