# Replace `a` by `1` and `ab` by `a`

Tags: regex

Given a string, I would like to replace all `ab`s by `a`, and all single `a`s by `1`, such that

```
X_ab_X-a%X
```

becomes

```
X_a_X-1%X
```

Replacing all `a`s or all `ab`s alone is pretty easy (here in JS)

```
mystring.replace(/a/gm, '1');
// mystring.replace(/ab/gm, 'a');
```

but I'm not seeing how to combine the two. All possible substrings can occur in `mystring` such that first replacing `ab` by `TMP_UNIQUE_STRING` won't work.

(Perhaps regexes aren't the right tool for the job.)

Comment: Replace them alone but start with `ab` and use `TMP_UNIQUE_STRING`. Three replacements in total.

Comment: Replace `ab` with some random string that never occurs in the wild, replace `a` with `1`, then replace your random string with `a`? Silly, but it uses non-regex string replacement and avoids turning `ab` all the way into `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Unfortunately, there is is no "string that never occurs in the wild". I'll try to make that even clearer in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace ,(comma) by .(dot) and .(dot) by ,(comma)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238005/replace-comma-by-dot-and-dot-by-comma)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with the callback.

```
var str = "X_ab_X-a%X".replace(/ab?/g, function($0) {
    return $0 === 'a' ? '1' : 'a';
});
```

Using ES6 Arrow functions,

```
"X_ab_X-a%X".replace(/ab?/g, $0 => $0 === 'a' ? '1' : 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regex with alternation, and inside a replace callback, check the value and replace accordingly:

```js
var re = /ab|a/g; 
var str = 'X_ab_X-a%X';
var result = str.replace(re, function(val) {
  return val === "ab" ? "a" : "1";
});
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Note that `ab` should come first in the alternation as the first branch matched "wins".

Comment: I suggest alternation because I surmise that `a` and `ab` are just placeholders and there can be other values. Surely, a final pattern can be optimized (as in Tushar's answer).

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
("X_ab_X-a%X").replace(/a(?!b)/gm, '1');
```

Lookahead Zero-Length Assertions are the best.