# Replace comma by point in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently working on a project in Qt, where the user can enter a value in a configuration to set it as global. This Value wll be stored in an .xml file where it is read from as well.

Because of me using c++ in Visual Studio, it only accepts a point: `14.6` is ok but `14,6` isn't. It doesn't throw an error, but the value will be saved as zero. I want to keep it in the xml  in the format with the point, for language reasons (German is the only language that needs a comma until this point, and the most languages use the point as separator as well)

I search something similar to : [Replace ,(comma) by .(dot) and .(dot) by ,(comma)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238005/replace-comma-by-dot-and-dot-by-comma) .
This answer referes to Javascript but I need it in c++.

I would like to know what would be the most efficient solution. I have alredy thought about "translating" it with regular expressions but I'm sure there are way more elegent and shorter ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to use `std::replace` function:

```
QString s = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ',', '.');
qDebug()<< s;
```

OR QString replace function:

```
QString s = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
s.replace(",", ".");
qDebug()<< s;
```

**Output:** `aaa.bbb.ccc`