# How to publish only bundled/minified scripts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, bundling-and-minification

I have a MVC4 project that is deployed to Azure. The bundling and minification works absolutely fine.

All the script files are in a folder /js which are bundled to /scripts/js

When I publish to Azure using msdeploy, I would like only the bundled/minified script files to be deployed. I don't want anyone getting access to my un-minified scripts by guessing the url.

I understand MVC bundling happens at runtime hence it would require the unbundled files to create the bundles on the fly. This probably needs to be automated with something like grunt maybe?

Want to know what deploy strategy people use in such cases when you dont want to publish unbundled js.

Comment: What did you do to solve this? I am having a similar case and want to stop serving files with their url, did you end up using grunt or is there another way?

Comment: dint get a solution as such. Using grunt or even web essentials bundling is the way to go i'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

using Web Deploy you can set the skip parameter:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx

here's a sample:

http://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/18/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/

Comment: but how do i minify all the files first?

Comment: just switch to release mode and build your project or you can create a build definition and use continuos integration to publish your website.

Comment: since it will publish a release mode, your files will be minified

Comment: No it doesn't minify.. The unminified files go live too. But only the minified files are served.

Answer (score 0):

They get your scripts on pageload, so I don't see why them seeing the unminified version should be a big concern, unless maybe you have crazy or offensive comments in your unminified version. Users could use a javascript formatter, like discussed [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript) to get the minified files back into a readable format.

Though, for your concerns, you could simply drop a web.config file in the deployed `/js` folder to keep anything from being served up. In my testing, this did not impact minification. Although if you put it in your local folder, you'll have errors bundling in debug mode (since debug mode serves up the individual files and this web.config keeps anything from being served):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Another concern is, depending on how paranoid you are at someone seeing an unminified script, you may have to write your own BundleBuilder class for reasons detailed in [How to prevent User-Agent: Eureka/1 to return source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991736/how-to-prevent-user-agent-eureka-1-to-return-source-code), which reveals how users can see unminified bundles with comments by changing their user-agent.