# ASP.NET stop user from accessing unbundled script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, security, bundling-and-minification

In my application I have script bundles which would bundle scripts and minify them when the site requests for them, I would like to know if it is possible to stop users from accessing the source script instead of the bundled and minified ones? I.E. the user should not be able to do `http://mydomain/script.js` to access the source script

Comment: FWIW I answered this [on this similar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789211/1810243)... can't mark as dupe since no answer was ever accepted... but his main issue was "I dont want anyone getting access to my un-minified scripts by guessing the url".

Comment: @SilverlightFox yea wouldnt hurt to find out how to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

Put your source script files in `App_Data`.

The `App_Data` folder is protected from the web by ASP.NET so no one can access `http://www.example.com/App_Data/script.js`. However, you can still read it locally from the file system.

You may need some modifications to your code to make available the `.js` file in a different URL path than the source (as they will need to be read from the web from a different path than `http://www.example.com/App_Data` - e..g `http://www.example.com/Scripts`)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to limit access to certain resources and files in the web.config.  To deny access to all users to a file, you can add the following:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <location path="script.js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your script in a folder instead of the root of your site (the same level as your web.config)?
I use this across all of my sites to limit access to unauthenticated users (using <deny users="?" />).  I am also using Forms Authentication, but that shouldn't keep this from working with the deny all *

Comment: I tried to put the script in root folder and it did not work. I can still request the scripts thru mydomain/script.js. doesn't work if I change the path to "Scripts" which is the folder for scripts too