# un minify JS (javascript) code using visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, minify, unminify

I am able to Un minify CSS using Visual studio shortcut (Ctrl + K + D). Same trick not working for JS files.

How can I un minify JS using Visual Studio like (Ctrl + K + D) short cut. I know there are lot of tools on web but i am searching for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8):

[Tool to Unminify / Decompress JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822119/tool-to-unminify-decompress-javascript)

You cannot *truly* unminify javascript, as minified javascript replaces variable names with letters, as well as removing code comments - these cannot be "undone" as the original information no longer exists.

It appears that you can at least recreate appropriate spacing, but "real" minified javascript cannot be undone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Prettier** https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html, to get the script slightly human readable.

If you are having problem with vs code you can add this in your settings.json

`"[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },`

It works for me for mega file...