# CSS and JS files having junk characters after publishing Asp.net website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am publishing an **asp.net** website and when I try to run it, the `CSS` and the `JS` files are not loading correctly. When I open the **Chrome debugger tools**, all the JS files are giving the following error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

and when I view the js files from the developer tools, they contain only junk characters. The thing is when I view the files on the file system, they appear to be fine but when I view them from the developer tools or from a browser e.g. http://localhost/MyApp/jquery.js, I see only junk characters

I've been trying to find out what's wrong but this error keeps coming. it was working before and all of a sudden I am getting this.
[image]

Comment: Current tools (Chrome Developer Tools / Fiddler etc) should be able to uncompress those and show them in a friendly view.

Comment: Hi Erik, I was debugging it through the chrome developer tools and it wasn't decompressing. the screen shot is taken from Chrome Developer tools. guess the server was compressing and sending it to the client.

Comment: Check out this SO Answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7149719/209259

Comment: Hi Erik, what I meant to say was that my code was not being minified, my js was getting replaced by some unreadable junk characters which my browser was unable to interpret. minified javascript files can be read by the browsers. a specific setting in my config file was somehow turning it into junk characters which was then sent on to the client side. the link that you've shared is talking about formatting minified files and its not relevant to my question. thanks anyways for helping.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't tell, the image is too small to debug.

Comment: Sorry about the image Erik. I thought we could enlarge it in Stack Overflow. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there was a key in my `web.config` that was compressing the javascript files on the fly.

I had the **GZip** compression key in my config file which was causing this issue.
here's the key

```
<add name="Headers_GZipOutput" type="Headers_GZipOutput"/>
```

I commented this and it started working.